# Prove for every $n,\;\;$ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor=n $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> **Problem**
>   Prove that for every nonnegative integer $n$ we have,
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor=n$$
>   where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the integer part of $x.$
>   Please give me a hint. Even, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Well, for starters, the sum only needs to go up until $2^k>2n$

Comment: Er, I meant $2^k\ge2n$

Comment: "Even, I don't know how to start" This is surprising. And what about computing the terms in the LHS for small values of $n$?

Comment: Here's a small but useful improvement you can make to your Question.  The "integer part" of $x$ might mean the nearest integer (which square brackets are sometimes used to represent), but more likely you mean the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  The latter is called the "floor" of $x$ and commonly expressed as $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in math notation.

Comment: Probably the reason some people are voting to close this is that it's phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.

Comment: @hardmath : I haven't seen that notation for nearest integer. Do you not remember a time when $[x]$ was the standard notation for what is now more often denoted $\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  I'm trying to suggest an improvement the OP can make.  If the OP is willing to clarify the notation for (and meaning of) "integer part", it would motivate my voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every nonnegative integer $n$ has a unique binary representation $n = \sum_{k=0}^{\ell} a_k 2^k$ where each $a_k \in \{0,1\}$. We have $$\frac{n}{2^j} = \sum_{k=0}^{\ell} a_k 2^{k-j} = \frac{a_0}{2^j} + \frac{a_1}{2^{j-1}} + \cdots \frac{a_{j-1}}{2} + a_j + 2a_{j+1} + \cdots + 2^{\ell-j} a_{\ell}.$$ Note that $$S_j:= \frac{a_0}{2^j} + \frac{a_1}{2^{j-1}} + \cdots \frac{a_{j-1}}{2} \le \frac{1}{2^j} + \frac{1}{2^{j-1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^j}$$ Furthermore, if $a_{j-1} = 0$, then in fact $S_j < 1/2$.

Set $A_j := \frac{n}{2^j} + \frac{1}{2}$. The inequality above implies that the integer part of $A_j$ is $A_j - S_j$ if $a_{j-1} = 0$ and $A_j - S_j + 1$ if $a_{j-1} = 1$, i.e. the integer part of $A_j$ is simply $A_j - S_j + a_{j-1}$.

Thus, we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lfloor A_j \rfloor = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j - S_j + a_{j-1} $$

We now compute this sum: $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j - S_j +a_{j-1} = \sum_{j=1}^{\ell+1} a_j + 2a_{j+1} + \cdots + 2^{\ell - j} a_{\ell} + a_{j-1} = a_{\ell} (2^{\ell-1} + 2^{\ell-2} + \cdots + 1) + a_{\ell-1} (2^{\ell-2} + \cdots + 1) + \cdots + a_2 (2+1) +a_1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\ell+1} a_{j-1} = 2^{\ell} a_{\ell} + 2^{\ell-1} a_{\ell-1} + \cdots + 2^2 a_2 + 2a_1 - (a_{\ell} + \cdots + a_1) + \sum_{j=1}^{\ell+1} a_{j-1} = 2^{\ell} a_{\ell} + 2^{\ell-1} a_{\ell-1} + \cdots + 2^2 a_2 + 2a_1 + a_0 = n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Why did you write
$ \sum_{j=1}^{\ell+1} a_j + 2a_{j+1} + \cdots + 2^{\ell - j} a_{\ell} + a_{j-1} $ not
$ \sum_{j=0}^{\ell} a_j + 2a_{j+1} + \cdots + 2^{\ell - j} a_{\ell} + a_{j-1} $??

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider this problem in binary:

Suppose, when written in binary form:
$$n=\overline{a_ma_{m-1}\cdots a_1}$$So that $n$ has m digits in binary, and each $a_i$ is either $1$ or $0$, $a_m \neq 0$.

In binary, dividing by 2 is like dividing by 10 in decimal, and adding $\frac{1}{2}$ is the same as adding $0.1$. Hence, for $k=1, 2, ..., m$,
$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ contributes to the summation.

Furthermore, for each $k=1, 2, ..., m$, $$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}\frac{n}{2^k} & \mbox{if} \ a_k=0\\ \frac{n}{2^k}+1 & \mbox{if} \ a_k=1\end{cases} $$
(why?)

So, we can write 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor 
=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{\overline{a_ma_{m-1}\cdots a_1}}{2^k}+|\{i:a_i=1\}|\\
=\overline{a_ma_{m-1}\cdots a_2}+\overline{a_ma_{m-1}\cdots a_3}+\cdots +a_m+|\{i:a_i=1\}|$$
Perhaps you can take it from here?

Comment: Please use answers for answers, not comments. If you do not do so, you may receive an answer suspension, which removes your answering privilege. On the other hand, if you write good answers as answers, you may receive upvotes, and it doesn't take many upvotes to unlock the comment privilege.

Comment: On the other hand, this could make a good answer. Why don't you [edit] what you have and make it an actually serious hint (the OP asks for a hint, and this does well)

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement :)

Comment: :-) no problem!

Answer (score 2):

The terms of $f_n(k)= \displaystyle \left[\frac{n}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ are integers by definition, and non-negative ones at that. Therefore you know that if the sum is to converge, there must be some $N$ such that for every $k>N$ we have $f_n(k)=0$.

Can you find this $N$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint, use this well known:
$$\left[x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right]=[2x]-[x]$$